# Highchart.js secondary axis not showing on the opposite side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

These are the options for the secondary axis:

```
{
  title: {
    text: 'This should be on the other side' 
  },
  opposite: true
}],
```

I expected it to show on the left, buy it does not. How can I show it on the left side?
http://jsfiddle.net/5XQT9/1/

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a `stockChart` the options for the `opposite` are the *opposite* !

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.opposite defaults to `true`
whilst http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.opposite defaults to `false`

Hence changing it to `false` as below will work: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/5XQT9/4/

```
{
        title: {
            text: 'This should be on the other side'
        },
        opposite: false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis)

> opposite: Boolean Whether to display the axis on the opposite side of
>   the normal. The normal is on the left side for vertical axes and
>   bottom for horizontal, so the opposite sides will be right and top
>   respectively. In Highstock 1.x, the Y axis was placed on the left side
>   by default. Defaults to true.

That means **Right is the opposite**.

So if you want Y-Axis to be on left then mark `opposite false` see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XQT9/3/)

```
 yAxis: [
                {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'

                },
                        opposite: false}, 
                    {
                        title: {
                            text: 'This should be on the other side' 
                        },
                        opposite: false
                    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I changed the order of the properties, setting first "opposite" and then all the others it render as expected.

```
{
    opposite: false,
    title: {
           text: 'This should be on the other side'
           },
    min: 0,
    ceiling: 100
}
```